# display data from table1 where its id (Table1 Id)is not contained in table2

Tags: sql

How can I display data from table1 where its id (Table1 Id)is not contained in table2

```
string Query = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1ID!=" Table2_Table1ID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Table1ID from Table2 where Table1ID=Table1.Id)
```

Comment: but if some rows in table1 is not contained in table2,how to show them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE table1ID NOT IN (SELECT table1ID FROM table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T2.Table1ID = T1.Table1ID
WHERE T2.Table1ID IS NULL
```

This will attempt to match records between Table1 and Table2 using the Table1ID value and only pull those where Table2.Table1ID is NULL (no match was found).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE able1ID NOT IN (SELECT table2id FROM table2)
```